# Why my Chrome and Firefox don't show images of my redirected HTM doc?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, firefox, google-chrome, ms-word

I have a product website made with ASP.NET MVC 3 and need to expose a document made with Word.
I exported the Word documento as HTM and redirected a view with...

```
public ActionResult OnLineProductManual()
{
    return Redirect(Url.Content("~/Content/Product_DocHtml/Product_Manual.htm")); 
}
```

All works fine enough on IE9, but the images are not displayed on Chrome and Firefox.
Internally (in the htm file) the images are referenced as...

```
<v:imagedata src="Product_Manual_files/image009.png"
 o:title="im_ico_64_v4" cropbottom="1f"/>
```

What can I do to show the images in these major browsers?

Comment: What happened to old `<img src="x.png">`?

Comment: The HTM file was exported from a Word document, which uses that way for referencing the images (saved in a folder, the "Product_Manual_files" in this case, at the same level of the HTM doc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use VML.  VML is not supported by Firefox, Chrome, or any non-microsoft browser really.

Either manually replace the vml tags by their html counterparts, or find another way to create your html files.  I would suggest the last approach.

For an online manual for which you have a word doc, PDF seems like a good solution.

Comment: I see. I have the manual in PDF but also I wanted to expose the info directly, no requiring a viewer. Thanks!